# How to skip validation of a few model fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a model User.

Here're a few validation fields:

```
validates :first_name, presence:{ message: "please add your First name"}
validates :last_name, presence:{ message: "please add your Last name"}
validates :username, presence:{ message: "please pick a username"},
```

When I try to sign up using devise, I have a message that I should provide first name and last name. But for registration I only want to use 3 fields shown: username, email, password.

How to skip validation of first and last names during registration?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the validations for `first_name`, `last_name` to run while creating a new user BUT you want them while updating an existing user record. All you need to do is , modify the validations such that they will only be run while `updating` a user record.

You can do this by using `on: :update` option as below:

```
validates :first_name, presence:{ message: "please add your First name"}, on: :update
validates :last_name, presence:{ message: "please add your Last name"}, on: :update
```